# Project Facets window background color issue on Dark theme

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes, tooltip

I am having an issue with eclipse in showing me the background color on Project Facets after applying **Eclipse Spectrum Dark Theme**

Here is my Project Facets window:

[image]

How can I change the background color on this window so that I can see the text on it?

Comment: How does it behave with the built-in Dark theme?

Comment: It behaves fine with the built in themes. But what should I do to make it work well with my current theme.

Comment: Report it as a bug to whomever makes that theme.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was expecting if I can do something on the eclipse side. I will raise a bug to the developer of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Since you reported it as as an issue, it is now a **known Eclipse Spectrum Theme issue** that will probably be fixed in a future release:

[Eclipse Spectrum Theme - Issue #127: *Issue with colors on Project Facets window*](https://github.com/AObuchow/Eclipse-Spectrum-Theme/issues/127)